# Aggregrate measurements per time period

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have a 6 x n matrix with the data: year, month, day, hour, minute, use.
I have to make a new matrix containing the aggregated measurements for use, in the value ’hour’. So all rows recorded within the same hour are combined. 
So every time the number of hour chances the code need to know a new period starts.
I just tried something, but I don't now how to solve this.
Thank you. This is what I tried + a test

```
def groupby_measurements(data):
    count = -1
    for i in range(9):
        array = np.split(data, np.where(data[i,3] != data[i+1,3])[0][:1]) 
    return array
print(groupby_measurements(np.array([[2006,2,11,1,1,55],
                             [2006,2,11,1,11,79],
                             [2006,2,11,1,32,2],
                             [2006,2,11,1,41,66],
                             [2006,2,11,1,51,76],
                             [2006,2,11,10,2,89],
                             [2006,2,11,10,3,33],
                             [2006,2,11,14,2,22],
                             [2006,2,11,14,5,34]])))
```

In this case I tried, I expect the output to be:

```
                   np.array([[2006,2,11,1,1,55],
                             [2006,2,11,1,11,79],
                             [2006,2,11,1,32,2],
                             [2006,2,11,1,41,66],
                             [2006,2,11,1,51,76]]),  
                   np.array([[2006,2,11,10,2,89],
                             [2006,2,11,10,3,33]]),
                    np.array([[2006,2,11,14,2,22],
                              [2006,2,11,14,5,34]])
```

The final output should be:

```
                   np.array([2006,2,11,1,0,278]),  
                   np.array([2006,2,11,10,0,122]),
                   np.array([2006,2,11,14,0,56])
```

(the sum of use in the 3 hour periodes)

Comment: aggregate_measurements expects two inputs, you only provided one.

Comment: sorry, data should not be there. changed it now

Comment: Write a function that create a dictionary, the keys of this dict are the hours and for each line it receives add a new key or aggregate new value to the existent keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using pandas Dataframes, and then using `groupby` combined with `sum`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
    [[2006,2,11,1,1,55],
    [2006,2,11,1,11,79],
    [2006,2,11,1,32,2],
    [2006,2,11,1,41,66],
    [2006,2,11,1,51,76],
    [2006,2,11,10,2,89],
    [2006,2,11,10,3,33],
    [2006,2,11,14,2,22],
    [2006,2,11,14,5,34]]),
    columns=['year','month','day','hour','minute','use'])

aggregated = data.groupby(['year','month','day','hour'])['use'].sum()

# you can also use .agg and pass which aggregation function you want as a string.
aggregated = data.groupby(['year','month','day','hour'])['use'].agg('sum')

year  month  day  hour
2006  2      11   1       278
                  10      122
                  14       56
```

Aggregated is now a pandas Series, if you want it as an array just do

```
aggregated.values
```

Comment: woops, a closing parenthesis was missing. Fixed now

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How can I acces each "sum" element?

Comment: `aggregated.values` will give you the answer as an array, then you can access the elements by indexing. eg: `aggregated.values[0]` is the first element